# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error | But I want multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

I've below query, into which I'm creating using a subquery which is returning

> **ORA-01427**: single-row subquery returns more than one-row error.

But I want all the values that subquery is returning, and there is no other column left for the join condition. Below is my sample query.

```
select name, 
       dob, 
       cdate, 
      (select value 
         from item a, 
              books b 
        where a.id = b.id 
          and a.newid = b.newid 
          and a.id = s.id 
          and a.bid = s.cid
          and a.eventid=1) col_value,
      (select value2
         from item a, 
              books b 
        where a.id = b.id 
          and a.newid = b.newid 
          and a.id = s.id 
          and a.bid = s.cid
          and a.eventid=1) col_value2
  from sample s, 
       purchase p
 where s.id = p.id
   and s.cid = p.cid
```

**Desired Output**

[image]

Do I need to apply a Group By? Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` the subquery instead.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Please use modern JOIN syntax, available since SQL-92, that is 28 years ago.

Comment: So, if you have three values, which one do you want? min, max, avg, sum?

Comment: `where a.id = b.id and a.newid = b.id` does not seem right

Comment: What if, I'll have more than one subquery? Due to some certain reasons I can't directly use JOIN. So please let me know is there any other possibility of doing this using an Outer Query or Group by

Comment: @TheImpaler for the rest of the three columns I believe Min would be fine.

Comment: @GMB corrected the typo...

Comment: @steve To produce a single row, use a subquery. To produce multiple rows use a JOIN. I think you want the latter; get rid of the subquery and write a join.

Comment: You said you "want all values". I think that means you need to use [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

Comment: @JeffHolt Please see my desired output.

Comment: Example data would go far to make it clear what you want and to expose the table relationships. Additionally, if the real problem is that you have more than one correlated subquery in your list of select items, then you should show two because that would make the MCV example more Complete wrt the actual concern you have.

Comment: @JeffHolt Thanks, I've updated my query and added one more subquery in my select clause and also updated the desired output. I believe, now it'll be more clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is little bit more difficult without data but try:

```
select name -- please use table alias so you know which table the value is from (s, p or cv)
       , dob
       , cdate
       , cv.value
from sample s 
left join purchase p on s.id=p.id and s.cid=p.cid --or just join
left join (select value, a.id, a.bid  --or just join
           from item a
           left join books b  --or just join
           on a.id=b.id and a.newid=b.newid) cv
on cv.id = s.id and cv.bid = s.cid           
left join (select value2
           from item a 
           left join books b 
           on a.id = b.id and a.newid = b.newid) cv2
on cv2.id = s.id and cv2.bid = s.cid
where cv2.eventid=1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my query and added one more subquery in my select clause and also updated the desired output. I believe, now it'll be more clear to you.

Comment: Hi @steve, you are welcome. I still stand with my answer. Have you tried it ? Please understand that we need the demo data from the start(from the tables)  with this "expected result" data to understand better. Also please explain this: "there is no other column left for the join condition"

Comment: I'm explaining my desired output: 
the Sample table is returning: Name and Dob.
Purchase table is returning: Cdate.
I've to bring value,value2 columns from Items Table and I can't directly do the Join of Items, Books, and Sample because of a condition ("where a.eventid=1" )
.If I apply this condition in Where outside the subquery, then it's filtering the record and only displaying 2 out of 3, but I want all three records to come.  Please refer to the Query once again.

Comment: I have updated my answer but as I said before the system of resolving is the same. Sorry but for more help you will need to add the data from the begining not only expected result data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, 
       dob, 
       cdate, 
      (select value 
         from  
              books b 
        where a.id = b.id 
          and a.newid = b.newid ) col_value,
      (select value2
         from 
              books b 
        where a.id = b.id 
          and a.newid = b.newid ) col_value2
  from sample s, 
       purchase p,item a
 where s.id = p.id
   and s.cid = p.cid
   and a.id(+)=s.id
   and a.bid(+)=s.cid
   and a.eventid(+)=1
```